# How to get launcher activity / intent without using package manager (for self package)

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a base code which is shared between 3 different packages.
I want to get the launcher activity for the current package, this is what I do today :

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
flag = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT;
return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, flag);
```

But I received a crash report for `Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died`
The used `context` belongs to a service which should be running, but as we all know, it can always stop due to system requirements.
I know I can catch the exception but then the launch intent will be missing.
I was hoping there is a less resource requiring method for getting the launch intent for the self package.

P.S. 
Another solution is having a some kind of a singletone initialized with the main activity by each package, but since the packageName is known on runtime, I want to think I can avoid implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

I can try to use a broadcast receivers that can catch events between packages.
So, you can send, store any data you want without killed events.

Comment: You mean to create a specific event which will be received by a designated broadcastReceiver ? Ill still have to implement 3 'same' broadcastReceiver , this is pretty much similar to the singletone solution.

Comment: @SagiLow broadcase receiver is 'android like' feature.

Comment: ill still have to implement receiver - per package, this is something I want to avoid

Comment: this is the most commont interaction between apps.

Comment: I understand, but here the situation is a bit different, I just need the launcher activity / intent, writing a BroadcastReceiver for getting it sounds like an overkill.